# Secure OSM instance and prevent unwanted access

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, apache

I just finished installing an OSM instance in a local VM. So far so good, tiles are being served just fine.

This VM will be public on internet, so my clients can access the tiles from my web page.

This web page, 'map.html' to give it a name, can be loaded by my users (user/password required), but as soon as they see the map they can inspect the HTML source code and see/copy the URL of my tiles server.

So, if they where in the mood, they could just create another webpage and access my tiles server.

That is the scenario I would like to prevent, but seems a little hard to accomplish.

How can I know that the access came from my 'map.html' and not from a 'fake.html'? How can I prevent access from unwanted pages?

This page 'map.html' runs on a fixed IP/DNS server online, maybe that can be used to secure access.

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org has a [question about implementing API key based access control for mod-tiles](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54221/implementing-api-key-based-access-control-for-mod-tiles). Restricting access to specific IP addresses is a different approach.

Comment: thanks a lot scai, but I think that does not solve my problem. What I do not want is for someone to figure out my URL and API and being able to call my server for whatever purposes he/she may have. I believe this api key can be easily found by any user, how do I restrict their access? IP based cannot be, as the tile fetching is done from the clients IP, and not my webserver IP, right? Thanks again, Federico.

Comment: Read https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/how-to-prevent-restrict-access-to-a-web-application-to-authorized-devices-only/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611072/how-to-secure-the-javascript-api-access-token. Short version: there is no simple solution. Don't worry about it unless it creates an actual problem. In this case you can still ban access from specific IP addresses. Also, not really a GIS question.